# how can show toast from service every 10 seconds

Tags: android

I have an android application and I want to show a notification or toast every 10 seconds for example from **Service** when application is closed or finished

Comment: "I have this class? please edit it." No. We are not a free editing service. Work this problem out and come up with a specific problem that has you stuck, and we'll help you out the best we can :)

Comment: user3404171 Not really. I never would have guessed that you didn't speak it as a first language

Comment: @user3404171 the point is, you cant just ask us to do some code for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have provided below a sample activity, a service class and a Timer class. use similar implementation in your application.

Activity Class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Sample extends Activity {

Button button1,button2;
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // Call the start and stop method when needed.    

}


public void Start(View v)
{
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Sample_service.class));

}

public void Stop(View v)
{
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Sample_service.class));

}

}
```

Service Class

```
package com.example.connect;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Sample_service extends Service{

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(Sample_service.this);

public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 10000);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    timer.cancel();
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Timer class

```
package com.example.connect;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {


private Context context;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
    this.context = con;
}



@Override
public void run() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "DISPLAY YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}

}
```

Comment: what is "Connect_service" on "Sample_service" class??

Answer (score 2):

I have given here three files,MainActivity,Manifest and MyService file implement it in your application and it will display toast service at every 10 seconds.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//load the layout file
        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));//use to start the services
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final long INTERVAL=10000;//variable to execute services every 10 second
    private Handler mHandler=new Handler(); // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Timer mTimer=null; // timer handling
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported Operation");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // cancel if service is  already existed
            if(mTimer!=null)
                mTimer.cancel();
        else
                mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);// schedule task
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "In Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//display toast when method called
        mTimer.cancel();//cancel the timer
    }
    //inner class of TimeDisplayTimerTask
    private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // display toast at every 10 second
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, When task is executed which you wrote in onCreate() method, It automatically close. For this you can use timer/scheduler.

Example :

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000);

timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                     
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
            }
};
```

Comment: You can use this code any where , In actvity or service class onCreate().

Comment: Use this piece of code in service class onCreate(). It will work :)

Comment: i tested it but returend Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) exception

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add your service in the manifest file inside the application Tag :

```
<service android:name=".ServiceGPS"
        android:permission="[Add permission here if exists]"
        android:label="[service name]" android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
</service>
```